# Windows 8.1 scale transform incorrect

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, scaletransform

I am designing a Windows 8.1 app in C#/XAML. I am trying to replicate the tilt effect found on Windows Phone. I have tried this with both a ScaleTransform and a PointerDownThemeAnimation.

However, the scale effect seems broken in the Y direction. It pushes the UI element down vertically on the page, instead of just scaling it smaller. I have used scale in Windows 8 apps before 8.1 and not had this issue.

Even stranger is in design view it works fine. I have tried setting RenderTransformOrigin to "0.5, 0.5". Here is an example of what happens when I set the text block's scale to 0.5:
[image]

What do you think the issue is and how can it be resolved? Thanks

Edit: Here is most of the XAML:

```
<Grid Height="{Binding PalettePanelHeight}">
                <TextBlock Text="Palettes" FontSize="70" Margin="24,22,0,0"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="typePanel" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,52,24,0">
                    <StackPanel.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,24,0"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Light"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="28"/>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Resources>
                    <TextBlock Text="Newest" Opacity="1" PointerPressed="on_PointerDown" PointerExited="on_PointerUp" PointerReleased="on_PointerUp" Tapped="newest_Tapped" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5"/>
                        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="Most popular" Opacity="0.45" PointerPressed="on_PointerDown" PointerExited="on_PointerUp" PointerReleased="on_PointerUp" Tapped="popular_Tapped" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="Highest rated" Opacity="0.45" PointerPressed="on_PointerDown" PointerExited="on_PointerUp" PointerReleased="on_PointerUp" Tapped="rating_Tapped" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
```

The 'Newest' text block with scale 0.5 is shown in the example image. 'PalettePanelHeight' is just Window.Current.Bounds.Height in code.

Comment: Show us the XAML? We can't guess what layout you've built here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the `ScaleTransform`, use VerticalAlignment to ensure that the text will be on top

```
<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Newest" Opacity="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5"/>
                    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                </TextBlock>
```

If you want to keep it like other titles, remove the scaleTrandform and make it:-

```
 <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Newest" Opacity="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
</TextBlock>
```